# React Hooks with React Router v4 - how do I redirect to another route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-hooks

I have a simple react hooks application - a list of Todos - with react router v4

On the List of Todos, when a Todo is clicked I need to:

1. Dispatch the current todo in context
2. Redirect to another route (from /todos to /todos/:id)

In the previous React Class based implementation  I could use this.context.history.push to redirect to another route.

How would I handle that using React Hooks in combination of React Router v4 (in code below see my comment in function editRow())?

Code below:

=====index.js=====

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom"

import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

=====main.js=====

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import TodosList from './todoslist'
import TodosEdit from './todosedit'

const Main = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/todos" component={TodosList}/>
      <Route exact path="/todos/:id" component={TodosEdit} />
    </Switch>
  </main>
)

export default Main
```

=====app.js=====

```
import React, {useContext, useReducer} from 'react';
import Main from './main'
import TodosContext from './context'
import todosReducer from './reducer'

const App = () => {
  const initialState = useContext(TodosContext);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(todosReducer, initialState);
  return (
    <div>
      <TodosContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>
        <Main/>
      </TodosContext.Provider>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;
```

=====TodosContext.js=====

```
import React from 'react'

const TodosContext = React.createContext({
    todos: [
        {id:1, text:'Get Grocery', complete:false},
        {id:2, text:'Excercise', complete:false},
        {id:3, text:'Drink Water', complete:true},
    ],
    currentTodo: {}
})

export default TodosContext
```

=====reducer.js=====

```
import React from 'react'

export default function reducer(state, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case "GET_TODOS":
            return {
                ...state,
                todos: action.payload
            }
        case "SET_CURRENT_TODO":
                   return {
                       ...state,
                       currentTodo: action.payload
            }
        default: 
            return state
    }
}
```

=====Todos.js=====

```
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import TodosContext from './context'

function Todos(){   
    const [todo, setTodo] = useState("")
    const {state, dispatch} = useContext(TodosContext)
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(state.currentTodo.text){
            setTodo(state.currentTodo.text)
        } else {
            setTodo("")
        }
        dispatch({
            type: "GET_TODOS",
            payload: state.todos
        })
    }, [state.currentTodo.id])

    const editRow = event =>{
        let destUrlEdit = `/todos/${event.id}`

        let obj = {}
        obj.id = event.id
        obj.text = event.text

        dispatch({type:"SET_CURRENT_TODO", payload: obj})

        //after dispatch I would like to redirect to another route to do the actual edit
        //destUrlEdit
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>List of ToDos</h1>
            <h4>{title}</h4>
            <ul>
                {state.todos.map(todo => (
                    <li key={todo.id}>{todo.text} &nbsp;
                        <button onClick={()=>{
                            editRow(todo)}}>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Todos;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is related to Programmatically navigating using react-router-v4 instead of with hooks,

In react-router-v4, you would get history from props if the Todos component is rendered as a child or Route or from an ancestor that is render form Route and it passed the Router props to it. However it is not receiving Router props, you can use `withRouter` HOC from `react-router` to get the router props and call `props.history.push(destUrlEdit)`

```
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import TodosContext from './context'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function Todos(props){   
    const [todo, setTodo] = useState("")
    const {state, dispatch} = useContext(TodosContext)
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(state.currentTodo.text){
            setTodo(state.currentTodo.text)
        } else {
            setTodo("")
        }
        dispatch({
            type: "GET_TODOS",
            payload: state.todos
        })
    }, [state.currentTodo.id])

    const editRow = event =>{
        let destUrlEdit = `/todos/${event.id}`

        let obj = {}
        obj.id = event.id
        obj.text = event.text

        dispatch({type:"SET_CURRENT_TODO", payload: obj})

        //after dispatch I would like to redirect to another route to do the actual edit
        //destUrlEdit
        props.history.push(destUrlEdit);
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>List of ToDos</h1>
            <h4>{title}</h4>
            <ul>
                {state.todos.map(todo => (
                    <li key={todo.id}>{todo.text} &nbsp;
                        <button onClick={()=>{
                            editRow(todo)}}>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default withRouter(Todos);
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply!! This pointed me in the right direction to explore accessing React Router props in React Class components vs React Functional components. One thing to add to your answer is since <Route> inherently gives the {history, match, location} props you do not need the HOC withRouter if the route is already defined and is at the main level. The props are accessible as is. But if the component is deeply nested then the HOC withRouter becomes helpful.

Comment: I wrote an article on this: https://dev.to/httpjunkie/programmatically-redirect-in-react-with-react-router-and-hooks-3hej and a sandbox example here: https://6wo1673y2r.codesandbox.io/

May help!

Comment: The React logs give the sense that a recursive state update is happening, which causes component to be unmount and then mounted again, but in the end the history unmount the component before the state is persisted, that's so strange.

Comment: @EricBishard I have been looking for hours something as simple as you suggest in your article. I think you should post it as an answer here.

Answer (score 23):

It's actually a lot simpler than the other answers, React Router v5.1 provides a [`useHistory`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const history = useHistory()
  const handleButtonClick = (event) => {
    history.push(event.target.value)
  }
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      value="/my/path"
      onClick={handleButtonClick}
    >
      Navigate Me!
    </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: I think it's actually v5.1 that introduces this feature: https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/

Comment: Yeah you're right! I've updated the version in my answer.

Comment: history.push('/') will still send the user to an old iteration of the page, though, you will still need to either put it inside of a useEffect and provide the useEffect with a variable to check for change, or provide props to your history via props.history.push('/'), where props are handed into the functional component.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UseNavigate` to move the change page. here is the sample example

"react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",

```
// Route File
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import IndexLayout from "../layouts";
import NotFoundPage from "../views/404";
import Loader from "../components/Loader";

const Dashboard = lazy(() => import("../containers/DashboardContainer"));

const Router = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <IndexLayout> // this one is kind of HOC
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={
              <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
                <Dashboard />
              </Suspense>
            }
          />

</end every thing>
// any component

import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const TestComponent = ({ newSignup }) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (newSignup) {
          navigate("/login");
        }
      }, [newSignup]);
    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default TestComponent
```

Comment: For anyone that misses the "^6.2.1" - you **need** to upgrade your react router to version 6 before being able to import useNavigate. See the docs for more info: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory

Answer (score 0):

Using react-redux and connected-react-router...

```
import {useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { push } from 'connected-react-router';

export default () => {
 const dispatch = useDispatch();

 return (
   <Button onClick={() => dispatch(push('/login'))}>
     Login
   </Button>    
  );
};
```

Comment: I get the error `Uncaught Could not find router reducer in state tree, it must be mounted under "router"`, even though everything is set up correctly from before I started using hooks. Old methods using component classes worked. Once I switched to this method I get that error.