# Redirecting using useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The idea is that I've got a component that renders something but in the meantime is checking something that will return or redirect to another component:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (() => {
    if (true) {
      // return to one component
    }

    // return to another component
  })();
});

return (
  <div> Javier </div>
);
```

I think that it is possible using the `useEffect hook`, but the problem is that, it does not redirect to my components, I tried using `Redirect` from the `react-router`, returning the component itself, and also using the `history` package, in this case, only replaced the url but no redirection at all.

Is this possible? Or maybe I'm way off the point.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: May be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54579730/react-hooks-with-react-router-v4-how-do-i-redirect-to-another-route

Comment: @jvrdom have a look at my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you are just needing conditional rendering you could do something like this:

```
const LoadingComponent = () => <div> Javier </div>

function Landing(props) {
    const [state={notLoaded:true}, setState] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        const asyncCallback = async () =>{
            const data = await axios.get('/someApiUrl')
            setState(data)
        }

        asyncCallback()
    },[]);

    if(!state){
        return <FalseyComponent />
    }
    if(state.notLoaded){
        //return some loading component(s) (or nothing to avoid flicker)
        return <LoadingComponent /> // -or- return <div/>
    }
    return <TruthyComponent />
}
```

or redirect completely:

```
const LoadingComponent = () => <div> Javier </div>

function Landing(props) {
    const [state={notLoaded:true}, setState] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        const asyncCallback = async () =>{
            const data = await axios.get('/someApiUrl')
            setState(data)
        }

        asyncCallback()
    },[]);

    if(!state){
        return <Redirect to='/falseyRoute' />
    }
    if(state.notLoaded){
        //return some loading component(s) or (nothing to avoid flicker)
        return <LoadingComponent /> // -or- return <div/>
    }
    return <Redirect to='/truthyRoute' />
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Using React router v6 you can create a redirection using useEffect:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, useNavigate,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Main />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
);

const Main = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    let didCancel = false;
    const goToHomePage = () => navigate('/home');
    if (!didCancel) { goToHomePage(); }
    return () => { didCancel = true; };
  }, [navigate]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome Main!</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome Home!</h1>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

If you want to create an alternative redirection to another component, you can do it as below:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, useNavigate,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Main />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/other" element={<Other />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
);

const Main = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    let didCancel = false;
    const goToHomePage = () => navigate('/home');
    const goToOtherPage = () => navigate('/other');
    if (!didCancel) { goToHomePage(); } else { goToOtherPage(); }
    return () => { didCancel = true; };
  }, [navigate]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome Main!</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome Home!</h1>
  </div>
);

const Other = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome Other!</h1>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

In React router 5 with changed old syntax it should also work. However, in React router 6 I did not find Redirect so the above redirection is more useful.

Comment: In React Router v6, `Redirect` was renamed to `Navigate`, just like `history` was renamed to `navigate`. Also, I prefer redirecting in a `useEffect`, instead of return a `<Redirect />` component.

Answer (score 4):

Try to return based on some state value like this.

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom"; //import Redirect first

const [redirctTo, setRedirctTo] = useState(false); // your state value to manipulate

useEffect(() => {
  (() => {
    if (true) {
      setRedirctTo(true)
    }

    // return to another component
  })();
});

if(redirctTo){
  return <Redirect to="/your-url" />
} else {
  return (
  <div> Javier </div>
);
}
```