# Why React Hooks doesn't update the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

I try to update the values in the ***useState*** with the fetched data.
when I ***console***.log ***data.success*** it returns ***true***. Then I assign it to the ***success*** value. but it returns ***false***! why? why value success doesn't get updated immediately. At the end i receive the message from the server that the login was successful.
SIGN IN success: false
the user admin is logged

```
const Signin = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    success: false
  });

  const { success } = values;

  const clickSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const signReact = catchAsync(async (email, password) => {
      const data = await signin(email, password) // fetch data from the server
      console.log(data.success); // -> true
      if (data) {
        setValues({
          ...values, success: data.success // -> assign to success
        });
        console.log("SIGN IN success: " + success); // -> false! why?!
      }
      return data;
    });

    signReact(email, password);
  };
```

Comment: setState() is an async function. It doesnot update immediatly

Comment: Check out this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60815245/react-doesnt-set-state-after-axios-finished-fetching/60820441#60820441 seems like this is the one you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). Try something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("SIGN IN success: " + values.success);
  }, [values]);

...
...
 const data = await signin(email, password);
 setValues(prevState =>{...prevState, success: data.success});
```

Comment: the problem is that I need to update the value "success" to redirect the page.
const redirect = () => { if (success) { return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/user" }} />;
    }
  };

Comment: well, this question was for hooks though. You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58444212/5124488

Comment: @MichalRutz to redirect on `api success` you can write as `{values.success&&<Redirect to={{ pathname: "/user" }} />}` as this will execute only when `success` is true

Answer (score 0):

`setState()` is an asynchronus function. So you cannot print it in the next statement.It will take some time.To see the updated state values you can log it in `useEffect()` like this

```
useEffect(()=>{

console.log(values);
},[values])
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

> Calls to setState are asynchronous - don’t rely on this.state to reflect the new value immediately after calling setState. Pass an updater function instead of an object if you need to compute values based on the current state:

Example:

```js
const Signin = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    success: false
  });

  const { success } = values;

  React.useEffect(()=> {
    console.log("SIGN IN success: " + success);
  }, [values]);

  const clickSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const signReact = catchAsync(async (email, password) => {
      const data = await signin(email, password) // fetch data from the server
      console.log(data.success); // -> true
      if (data) {
        setValues({
          ...values, success: data.success // -> assign to success
        });
      }
      return data;
    });

    signReact(email, password);
  };
```