# React doesn't set state after axios finished fetching

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, axios, react-hooks

I'm writing client side code for authentication with React and react-router. In the code below, I want to check jwt token on the server. After that, I'll get `response.data.access` from server and I want to set it to `access` variable on client. But it seems it passes `false` to the protected route even if it logs `true` in the console. How can I set `access` properly? I guess the problem is in asynchronous code, and `setAccess` function is called without waiting for axios to fetch.

```
// imports

function App() {

  const [access, setAccess] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch();
  }, [access]);

  const fetch = async () => 
    await axios.get('http://localhost:7000/user/check-token')
      .then(response => {
        // response.data.access is a boolean variable coming from server
        console.log(response.data.access)
        setAccess(response.data.access);
      });

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>

        // other routes

        <Protected path='/user/dashboard' access={access}>
          <Dashboard userData={userData} />
        </Protected>

      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here's the protected route

```
 const Protected = ({ children, access, ...rest }) => {

    return (
      <div>
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
          access === true
            ? children
            : <Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/user/login',
                state: { from: props.location }
              }} />
        )} />
      </div>

    );
  }
```

Could you please explain what is happening and what should I do?

Comment: If you want to get it only for the first time when app renders then just remove [access] from the dependency i.e   useEffect( ( ) => {
    fetch( );  }, [ ] );

Comment: but it doesn't make any sense if [access] doesn't reach the private route, and this is what the problem is

Comment: Please share the full code or create a minimal example of your code i.e in codesandbox

Comment: thank you, but I've already solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. Well, I just added a loading screen to wait some time while data is fetching, and it solved my problem.

```
const Protected = ({ children, access, ...rest }) => {


    return (
      <div>
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => {
         if (access === null) {  // if access is null, the data is still being fetched
          return <h1>Loading...</h1>  // display loading hardcoded loading screen while it's not fetched
         } else {
          if (access === true) {
            return children
          } else {
            return <Redirect to={{
              pathname: '/user/login',
              state: { from: props.location }
            }} />
          }

         }

        }} />
      </div>

    );
  }
```