# Infinite loop when redirect on home loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I like to prefetch some data ahead of time so I prepared the routes and the loader like below and I'm getting infinite loop. Someone to suggest what is wrong and how I fix this.

homeLoader function:

```js
  homeLoader: async (queryClient) => {
    queryClient.ensureQueryData(['someKey'], doSomething);
    return redirect(`workspaces/1`); // Infinite loop happens
  }
};
```

router for the RouterProvider:

```
createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route
      path='/'
      element={<Home />}
      loader={() => homeLoader(queryClient)} // React Query injected
    >
      <Route path='workspaces' element={<Workspaces />}>
        <Route path=':workspaceId' element={<Workspace />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  )
)

<RouterProvider router={router} />
```

React and Router versions:

```json
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.14.2"
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling a redirect in the loader. The loader is meant to just fetch data for the route you are redirecting to. So if you call a redirect in the loader itself, it will cause the infinite loop. Why are you trying to redirect as part of the loader?

Comment: @M0nst3R because that's how our routes are structured (first '/' then goes to some child route), and we have immediate redirect (after some data is available from the server). I don't like to use useEffect and index route, but to make redirect through the loader.

Comment: What's wrong with `useEffect()`? At least it won't cause an infinite loop. Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444065/redirecting-using-useeffect-hook) and see if it helps you.

Comment: @M0nst3R Just I don't like it, I like more naive approach. I already have the implementation with useEffect, but I was expecting the loader once per route.

Comment: _I was expecting the loader once per route._ The problem is loader causes another route, which causes the loader, which causes the route...

Comment: @M0nst3R manage to fix as:

          <Route
            path='/'
            element={<Home />}
            loader={() => homeLoader(queryClient)}
          >
            <Route
              index
              loader={() => redirect('someRoute')}
            />

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to curry the `queryClient` to the loader function. The `homeLoader` could be rewritten to accept a `queryClient` argument ***and then*** return a function that serves as the loader function for the route.

Additionally, unconditionally returning a redirect from the loader is the likely cause of the render looping. If you want `"/"` to render a "default route" then use the `Navigate` component and issue the redirect from an index route.

Example:

```js
homeLoader: (queryClient) => () => {
  queryClient.ensureQueryData(['someKey'], doSomething);
}
```

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
  Navigate,
} from 'react-router-dom';

...

createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route
      path='/'
      element={<Home />}
      loader={homeLoader(queryClient)} // React Query injected
    >
      <Route index element={<Navigate to="/workspaces/1" replace />} />
      <Route path='workspaces' element={<Workspaces />}>
        <Route path=':workspaceId' element={<Workspace />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is looks better, with the Navigate component. What the currying will help me (I can't make it work the redirect, if I change the function with currying), I saw the same way of writing the loader on the RQ blog: rq client meets react router.

Comment: @ИгорТашевски Are you asking what/how writing a curried function helps? It basically saves passing an anonymous callback function. For example, instead of something like `myFunction = (customArg, event) => { ... }` and `callback: event => myFunction(customArg, event)` where the anonymous function exists only to proxy the event arg, you can curry the event arg with `myFunction = customArg => event => { ... }` and then `callback: myFunction(customArg)`.  Sorry if using currying here has caused any confusion, the main issue was the loader returning a redirect.

Comment: More I liked to ask, how curriyng helps in react router context, but it didn't help me in my case I like to take rid of some useEffects per page, and just move that useEffect code into this loader function (even sometimes I don't fetch anything), so I moved the ReactQueryProvider in index.tsx file, and instead inject it, I can use the same queryClient instance with: queryClient = useQueryClient(), and call the loaders without any params.

Comment: @ИгорТашевски No benefit, or detriment, of using the curried loader function in relation to React-Router. They are independent. Using a curried function is more of a preference I suppose, but functionally it is the same as using the anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, the fact is that when you use a loader on a route with daughter routes, the loader is activated both when you enter the root route and when you enter its daughters, and that causes the infinite loop, because the loader redirects you to a route that will execute the loader again, for this what I did was create two routes with the same address, one of them with the index property and the loader to redirect, while the other only contained the daughter routes or those that were wanted navigate, which when the loader is executed it redirects you to the other auxiliary route and no loop occurs, something like this in my example:

```
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        index: true,
        loader: () => {
            // Here you redirect to the preferred route
            return redirect('/dashboard/manager')
        },
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        children: [
            {
                path: 'manager',
                element: <ManagerLayout />,
                children: routesManager
            },
            {
                path: 'receptionist',
                element: <ReceptionistLayout />,
                children: routesReceptionist
            }
        ]
    },
```

In my case it worked, but I couldn't tell you if there is another or more optimal way.